# How to mock an async action creator with jest

Tags: unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I am learning unit/integration testing with Jest and Enzyme and getting stuck on how to mock an async action creator.

To be more accurate, my goal is to write a test to check if `fetchComments()` is called when the app is mount in the `App.tsx` file below (irrelevant code is omitted, see the whole code [here](https://github.com/buiquanghuy23103/my-restaurant/blob/unit-testing/src/App.tsx)).

```js
export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchDishes());
    dispatch(fetchLeaders());
    dispatch(fetchComments());
    dispatch(fetchPromotions());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        {/* code omitted */}
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've done the following steps to achieve the goal:

1. Create a fake Redux store with middleware for testing as shown below. You also can see the real Redux store implementation [here](https://github.com/buiquanghuy23103/my-restaurant/blob/5635652355ea988d5204eae29c8ebac0b6fdceed/src/redux/configureStore.ts#L19-L21).

```js
export const storeFactory = (initialState: AppState = defaultAppState) => {
    return createStore(appReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
}
```

2. Mock `fetchComments()` action creator. The real implementation of the action creator is in [/src/redux/comment/commentActions.ts](https://github.com/buiquanghuy23103/my-restaurant/blob/unit-testing/src/redux/comment/commentActions.ts) file, and the mock implementation is in [/src/redux/comment/**mocks**/commentActions.ts](https://github.com/buiquanghuy23103/my-restaurant/tree/unit-testing/src/redux/comment/__mocks__) file. And here is how I mock it:

```js
module.exports = {
    ...jest.requireActual('../commentActions.ts'),
    __esModule: true,
    fetchComments: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        type: INIT_COMMENTS,
        payload: []
    })
}
```

3. And finally write test in ```App.test.tsx`` file

```js
jest.mock('./redux/comment/commentActions');
const fetchComments: jest.Mock = require('./redux/comment/commentActions').fetchComments;


const setup = () => {
    const store = storeFactory();
    return mount(
        <Provider store={ store }>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    )
};

describe('fetch data on app mount', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        fetchComments.mockClear();
    });

    test('should fetch comments on app mount', () => {
        const wrapper = setup();
        expect(fetchComments).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    })

});
```

But I got the following error message:

```
Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

      24 |     dispatch(fetchDishes());
      25 |     dispatch(fetchLeaders());
    > 26 |     dispatch(fetchComments());
         |     ^
      27 |     dispatch(fetchPromotions());
      28 |   }, []);
      29 | 

      at dispatch (node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:206:13)
      at dispatch (node_modules/redux-thunk/lib/index.js:14:16)
      at App (src/App.tsx:26:5)
      at commitHookEffectListMount (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19731:26)
      at commitPassiveHookEffects (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19769:11)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188:14)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:318:25)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237:16)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292:31)
      at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22853:9)
      at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:12)
      at runWithPriority$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11039:10)
      at flushPassiveEffects (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22820:12)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21737:3)
      at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11089:24
      at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:12)
      at runWithPriority$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11039:10)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11084:7)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueue (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11072:3)
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21862:7)
      at Object.act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:929:14)
      at wrapAct (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:405:13)
      at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:474:16)
      at new ReactWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:115:16)
      at mount (node_modules/enzyme/src/mount.js:10:10)
      at setup (src/App.test.tsx:14:12)
      at Object.test (src/App.test.tsx:36:25)
```

I searched the error message on StackOverflow and all answers suggest that I should add middleware to the Redux store. But I already did that! So I think there might be some hidden mistakes in my code. I hope that someone can help me point it out.

Comment: Where does `mount` come from? Do you use `enzyme` package?

Comment: Yes, the ```mount()``` method is from ```enzyme```.

Comment: Redux's [guide for testing async actions](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#async-action-creators) recommends using [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store).

Comment: But I don't want to test the async action. I just want to mock it and chekc if it is called by the Apo component. The test target is the App component.